# Test on completable future always passing

Tags: java, junit, java-8, completable-future

I have the following test which should always fail:

```
@Test
public void testCompletable() {
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0)
        .thenAccept(a -> {
            org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(1==0);
        });
}
```

And this test always succeed. How can I make this test fail correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never try to retrieve the result of the completable future.

[`completedFuture(0)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) will return a completable future that is already completed with a result of 0. The consumer added with [`thenAccept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAccept-java.util.function.Consumer-) will be invoked and will return a new completable future. You can verify that it is called by putting a print statement in it:

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0)
.thenAccept(a -> {
    System.out.println("thenAccept");
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(1==0);
});
```

This will print `"thenAccept"` in the console. However, this new completable future completes exceptionally, since `Assert.assertTrue` throws an exception. That doesn't mean the exception is thrown to the caller: it simply means that we now deal with a completable future that is exceptionally completed.

So it is when we try to retrieve the value that the caller will have an exception. With [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--), a `ExecutionException` will be thrown and with [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--), a `CompletionException` will be thrown. As such, the following

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0)
.thenAccept(a -> {
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(1==0);
}).join();
```

will fail.

Comment: You could use Assert.fail() instead of Assert.assertTrue(1==0) it sounds more valid in this case, don't you agree?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Sure, but we don't know what case this is. Obviously, this test isn't the real one OP has, I assume this is a MCVE -- if they did, the entire test would be pointless anyway because it would be testing the JDK.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done like this:

```
@Test
public void testCompletable() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture completableFuture = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(0)
        .thenAccept(a -> Assert.fail());
    // This will fail because of Assert.fail()
    completableFuture.get();
}
```